# GIT: Changed File Names With Certain Extension

Tags: git, version-control, subdirectory, git-diff

When I want to get a list of the files I have changed so for, I use this command:

```
git diff --name-only
```

But many times, I get many files that I don't care about right now. For example, if I am uploading to my PHP server, I usually just want the list of .php files. I tried this:

```
git diff --name-only **/*.php
```

But unfortunately, it only shows me files in the first sub-directory. So looks like it is not interpreting the double star as recursive.

Any idea?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

just leverage grep:

```
git diff --name-only | grep .php
```

Comment: This solution looks much easier. I should have thought of it, thanks man :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
git diff --name-only '**/*.php'
```

(note the quotes)

**Edit**

Most POSIX shells don't support that pattern. From your comment, I gather that git doesn't either (I cannot test right now).

A workaround could be

```
git diff --name-only $(find . -name \*.php)
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I get this error: "fatal: ambiguous argument '**/*.php': unknown revision or path not in the working tree."

Comment: Thanks. The other one worked, but I am wondering about the meaning of the $ sign and the forward slash (\) before *.php?!

Comment: $(...) executes the command inside and replaces it by the command output. The backslash makes the shell treat the star as itself (thus passing it to find) instead of expanding it (you could have used quotes to the same effect).

Answer (score 2):

Use quotes to get git to perform the filter:

`git diff --name-only "*.php"`

Comment: Is it really that simple! wow!